# Using NSTimer close UIAlertView

Tags: iphone

I hope to use an UIAlertView prompt to reminder user some messages, the alerview will be closed automatically in 2 seconds.

my codes:

```
IBOutlet UIAlertView *aUIAlertView;
```

....

```
@property (retain,nonatomic)    IBOutlet UIAlertView *aUIAlertView;
```

....

```
        UIAlertView * alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]
                             initWithTitle: @"Reminder"
                                   message: @"Message" 
                                  delegate:self
                                 cancelButtonTitle:nil
                             otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(timerFired1:)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:NO]; 
        aUIAlertView=alert;
        [alert show];




- (void)timerFired1:(NSTimer *)timer {


    [aUIAlertView release];//I set the breakpoint here, aUIAlertView is not nill


}
```

timer was prompted, aUIAlertView is not nil.
but the alertview still displayed rather than was closed as I hoped.

Welcome any comment

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply sending the `-release` message to an object does *not* guarantee that it will be deallocated. In fact, in this case, it's almost certain that it won't be deallocated, since the system is currently displaying it.

The message you want to send when your timer fires is [dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIAlertView/dismissWithClickedButtonIndex%3aanimated%3a).